# How to Store Image File to List in Dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart, image-processing

How I can store ImageData to List in dart ??

so I want to store Image to My List but I dont know what type Data to put on

Like there are different that I know like File and FileImage ? I want to use it in my flutter app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use [File](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-io/File-class.html) as your dataType and for the list of files you can use something like [List](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/List-class.html) this List<File> imageListInFile = []
2. You can also use [Uint8](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-ffi/Uint8-class.html) (but use this where you have image in bytes) List<Uint8> imageListInBytes = []
3. You can also use List<String> as you can store list of images path you got from network or device

Comment: Yes I want to use File type 
but the problem is I want to backup that to firebase storage and I dont want to make it to huge 

is there advice or optimization I must do ?

Comment: Can you pls elaborate the scenario in which you want to save the files? So I can help

Comment: so I have a record of transaction which is normal List like userName,address and so on 
i want to store Image which is user upload to that List

Comment: I want to ask is there are different for a file size if iam use FIle or Uint8list ?? 
I dont want to make it huge and perfomance different between type cause I know someone store them as Base64 but this is take long operation because you must decode and encode that file on the run

Comment: In this case go with the File only if you receive image from api , probably it would be in Uint8List, you can convert to file or upload in bytes, your choice